# Get the position of a DOM element via x, y co-ordinates

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there a way to select the top most DOM element at a certain x-y position with Javascript?

So give x and y, what DOM element is there?

Comment: How are you getting the (x, y) in this case? If with a click, the top-most element's click handler will be fired.

Comment: No I just need to know without a click knowing if something is on the page or not at a certain position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`document.getElementFromPoint`](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#t20).